# MediaTomb enable/show up subtitles?

Tags: subtitle, dlna, mediatomb

How to make subtitles(sub, srt) to show up on video streamed by MediaTomb to Panasonic TV?

Answer (score 1):

First you will need a really powerfull setup to do this, depending on what formats your tv support. I used to used to stream to ps3 and had to almost transcode everything.

To add subtitles you can use 'vlc' with the '--sub-autodetect-file' parameter.

You will need to enable transcoding for mediatomb, there is a whole document on the mediatomb site that describes how to enable transcoding:
http://mediatomb.cc/pages/transcoding

I would recommend using a script instead of calling the vlc command directly, that way you can make easy changes to your script without the need to restart mediatomb.

In the end, this was the script that worked best for me, on the ps3, but again, you will need to make changes depending on what your TV supports.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

VLC=`which vlc`
MEDIAINFO=`which mediainfo`
XMLSTAR=`which xmlstarlet`
INPUT="$1"
OUTPUT="$2"
VIDEO_CODEC="mpgv"
VIDEO_BITRATE="4096"
VIDEO_FRAMERATE="25"
AUDIO_CODEC="a52"
AUDIO_BITRATE="192"
AUDIO_SAMPLERATE="48000"
AUDIO_CHANNELS="2"
FORMAT="ps"
SUBTITLE_LANGUAGE="nl"

VLC_VID_OPT="vcodec=${VIDEO_CODEC},vb=${VIDEO_BITRATE},fps=${VIDEO_FRAMERATE},soverlay,threads=2"

AUDIO_FORMAT=`${MEDIAINFO} --Output=XML "${INPUT}" | ${XMLSTAR} sel -t -m ".//track[@type='Audio']" -v "Format"`
case ${AUDIO_FORMAT} in
"AC-3" | "MPEG Audio" )
        VLC_AUD_OPT="audio-sync" ;;
* )
       VLC_AUD_OPT="acodec=${AUDIO_CODEC},ab=${AUDIO_BITRATE},samplerate=${AUDIO_SAMPLERATE},channels=${AUDIO_CHANNELS},audio-sync" ;;
esac

exec "${VLC}" -v "${INPUT}" -I dummy --sout "#transcode{${VLC_VID_OPT},${VLC_AUD_OPT}}:standard{mux=${FORMAT},access=file,dst=${OUTPUT}}" --sub-autodetect-file --sub-autodetect-fuzzy=1 --freetype-rel-fontsize=18 --sout-mux-caching=1500 --file-caching=1500 vlc:quit

exit 0
```

note: uses extra packages like mediainfo & xmlstarlet.

edit: that is a bunch of questions!
First of, i no longer use mediatomb because it was unstable, aparently you have the same issue as after some amount of time it no longer is accesable through dlna/upnp.

Anyway, i suggest you add logging in the script so you can see what is going on. Normally you should get your subtitles everywhere, not just on one device and not another.

It works in another way for file/media types, probably you are only transcoding a certain range of files because it works with some and not with others.

Comment: This is the bash code http://pastebin.com/zEzUPeCe and this is the xml config(/home/radibg2/.mediatomb/config.xml) - http://pastebin.com/5fiQdyDf when start a .mkv with cyriclic subs(.srt) it don't recognize them, if they are latin(en) it recognize them, how to fix that?

Comment: Edit - when start a .mkv with cyriclic subs(.srt - cp1251) it recognize them, if they are latin(en-utf8) it don't recognize them, also it is not recognizing any subs on .avi how to fix that?

Comment: Also mediatomb dissapears after some time from the dlna servers list but can connect to the web part.

Comment: I make it not to dissapear with this - https://gist.github.com/betacar/1556720, made the subtitles on any encoding/language/format to run, but only on my phone, on the TV in PC Directory is empty. Can you tell me why?

Comment: BTW by only on my phone i had in mind that there the videos and subtitles shown up ok. I make it show up, but there are still no subs on the films(i have tried with the code from your answer and from the link that i posted in my previous comment). So, how to show up the subs and on the TV?

Comment: I have tried mp4, avi, mkv in utf-8, cp-1251 and no subs shown up.

Answer (score -1):

If you are re-encoding with vlc, just add soverlay into your vlc script. Name the .srt same as your movie and have both in same directory.

piece of example script;

```
#transcode{venc=ffmpeg,vcodec=mp2v,vb=4096,fps=25,soverlay,aenc=ffmpeg, ...
example of file naming;
mymovie.mp4
mymovie.srt
```

works.